# Subscribing to mails

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am setting up a service that is supposed to handle outgoing and incoming mails from a CRM. I am stuck at handeling incominging emails. In theory it is easy, I can just use /messages to look through the inbox or set up a subscription by using the [webhook API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks?view=graph-rest-beta). However there is one main issue with this; privacy of private emails. I don't want to see or receive a notification on a message that is not stemming from our service. I tried adding an open extension and filtering bythis, but open extensions is not added to the replies of a message. My idea was to use something like this:

```
{
            changeType: "created",
            // Change url here
            notificationUrl: "https://b27dc6dc.ngrok.io/microsoft/mail/notification",
            resource:
                "me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages?$filter=Extensions/any(f:f/id eq 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension.Com.Contoso.Referral')", 
            expirationDateTime: "some date",
        };
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mail permissions give you access to all emails in the inbox it's consented for. There's no notion of only accessing a subset of emails in the inbox. The mail.read.basic permission gives you access to fewer properties (body is not accessible). You should evaluate whether this permission is enough for what you're trying to build.

Support for filtering notifications is very limited and varies from entity to entity. You can upvote the [existing uservoice idea](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/19081306-add-select-and-filter-to-webhook-resource-subs) to help prioritize the work and also get notifications when progress is made.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Greatly appreciated.